# Errata for Vinberg's "a course in algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I'm reading Vinberg's "a course in algebra" to have a basic understanding. I wonder if there is an errata for the book?

For example, Example 1.52 on page 23 talks about "$x^2+x+1=0$" , however I suspect it shall be "$x^2+x-1=0$" .

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a typo, your suspicion is correct.